# Error while creating entity in Doctrine using maker bundle

Tags: doctrine-orm

I tried creating an entity using php bin/console make:entity in my symfony project. I get the following error.

```
In AnnotationException.php line 53:
[Creation Error] An error occurred while instantiating the annotation @ApiResource declared on class App\Entity\MyEntityName: "Argument 1 passed to ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource::__construct() must be o  
  f the type string or null, array given, called in /MyDirectory/Projects/MyProject/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/DocParser.php on line 1493".  

In ApiResource.php line 172:
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  Argument 1 passed to ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource::__construct() must be of the type string or null, array given, called in /MyDirectory/Projects/MyProject/vendor/doctrine/annotatio
  ns/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/DocParser.php on line 1493
```

Entries in my composer.json is as follows:

```
{
    "name": "app/projectname",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "description": "Project Description ",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.5",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "api-platform/core": "^2.7",
        "doctrine/annotations": "1.14.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.10",
        "fig/link-util": "^1.1",
        "mpdf/mpdf": "^8.1",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.28",
        "symfony/asset": "^5.4",
        "symfony/console": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "^5.4",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.17|^2",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.8",
        "symfony/property-access": "^5.4",
        "symfony/property-info": "^5.4",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "^5.4",
        "symfony/runtime": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "^5.4",
        "symfony/serializer": "^5.4",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^5.4",
        "symfony/validator": "^5.4",
        "symfony/yaml": "^5.4",
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "^6.6"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.4",
        "dompdf/dompdf": "^2.0",
        "mitoteam/jpgraph": "^10.2",
        "phploc/phploc": "^7.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.7",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "^5.4",
        "symfony/http-client": "^5.4",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.43",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^6.2",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^5.4",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "5.4.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/package-versions-deprecated": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.4.*"
        }
    }
}
```

I had to install doctrine/annotations 1.14.3 because the doctrine/orm didn't automatically install it. Intalled fig/link-util because the page on packagist indicated a dependecy for api-platform/core and it wasnt installed automatically.

The make:entity utility fails the moment I specify that the entity should be flagged as an API Platform resourtce, it doesnt go on to accepting the attributes. Tried googling this but no one seems to have reported it. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: You have a few things in your composer.json file that makes me think this might be an upgrade or perhaps you did some extensive hand editing?  If you still have issues consider creating a new 5.4 api app and see if make:entity still complains.  If it doesn't that you can add your third party stuff and then replace your current composer.json file.  This stuff about how you had to add stuff manually is a bit of a red flag.

Comment: Let me try. Will post the results.